# Weird Domain handling for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cross-domain

I have a really weird issue. My customer wants to have a website structure that ist like the following:

```
www.mydomain.com/myapplication/de/
www.mydomain.com/myapplication/at/
www.mydomain.com/myapplication/ch/
```

They have installed Wordpress to the /de/ folder.
Now they want to also reach the same wordpress-installation by going to /at/ and /ch/ but keeping this URL-Fomat.

so
[www.mydomain.com/myapplication/de/a-wordpress-page.php](http://www.mydomain.com/myapplication/de/a-wordpress-page.php)
should also be reachable like:
[www.mydomain.com/myapplication/at/a-wordpress-page.php](http://www.mydomain.com/myapplication/at/a-wordpress-page.php)
[www.mydomain.com/myapplication/ch/a-wordpress-page.php](http://www.mydomain.com/myapplication/ch/a-wordpress-page.php)

Unfortunately putting the wordpress-application to the maindomain is not an option, due to their weird system...

I hope is understandable.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy.
You can redirect or rewrite your `/myapplication/at/` and `/myapplication/ch/` URL paths to the main `/myapplication/de/` using a RewriteRule in htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^myapplication/(at|ch)/(.*)$ /myapplication/de/$2 [L,R]
```

Put this at the top of your WordPress htaccess file.
And change `R` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirection is working perfectly fine.

If you want to keep the URL format  then just remove the `R` flag from the rule. The rule with `R` will make an invisible redirection of URLs.